# Android / Gradle - Artifacts (aar) with dependencies

Tags: android, artifactory, android-gradle-3.0

I have deployed an artifact (aar) with **dagger** dependency to my local artifactory. When I use the artifact in a project, it crashes at run-time due to the following exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "dagger.internal.Preconditions" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.se.tncdemo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.se.tncdemo-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at com.se.tnc.di.DaggerTNCComponent$Builder.tNCModule(DaggerTNCComponent.java:75) 
        at com.se.tnc.TNCManager.<init>(TNCManager.java:121) 
        at com.se.tnc.TNCManager.init(TNCManager.java:96) 
        at com.se.tncdemo.TNCApp.onCreate(TNCApp.java:21) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dagger.internal.Preconditions
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
```

Here is my dependency decleration:

```
implementation 'xxx:yyy:zzz'
```

I guess the workaround would be, adding the dagger dependency to the project. But, I don't want this.

Comment: What was your solution?